# Spanish (Castillian) idiom to "talk your way out of something."

Tags: modismos

To "talk your way out of something," means to avoid something bad happening to you by (usually) persuading your opponent with convincing argument, an offering, an excuse, or some other similar verbal gesture.

> The police officer was going to give me a ticket for speeding, but I
> talked my way out of it.

In other words, I persuaded him not to give me the ticket.

Comment: to talk your way out of something, is an idiom for=to convince someone not to do something to you. convencerle de no hacerlo. That's what comes to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguro. Una posibilidad sería **pilotearla**.

> El policía me iba a multar por exceso de velocidad, pero la **piloteé** (la ‘pilotié’ para sonar más callejero).

Answer (score 1):

["Bailar al agua"](https://www.cope.es/emisoras/catalunya/barcelona-provincia/barcelona/la-linterna-cope-catalunya-i-andorra/noticias/cual-origen-expresion-bailar-agua-alguien-20210125_1105340#:%7E:text=Se%20utiliza%20expresiones%20como%20%27Bailar,como%20%27hacerle%20la%20pelota%27.):

> **¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión ‘Bailarle el agua a alguien’?** Se
> utiliza expresiones como ‘Bailar el agua’ o ‘Bailarle el agua a
> alguien’ para referirse al hecho de halagar y adular a una persona (lo
> que hoy en día diríamos como ‘hacerle la pelota’).

Answer (score 0):

You can use apalabrar. Meaning come to agreement with words. But also bribe, or give them an offer they could not refuse
Apalabrar es una version. Significado llegar a un acuerdo con palabras, sobornar, propinar o, tal vez darles unas opciones, como, “plata o plomo?”

Comment: I think that "apalabrar" does not convey the same meaning of the idiom "talk your way out of something". It's not even an idiom, it's just a verb.

Comment: Why use an idiom, if you can say it with one word? Waste of breath.   Mire, compita. El otro dia por alla me pararon los chotas, por andar accelerado. Pero tengo mañas. Los apalabre. Ya tu sabes?!                 Do you think i talked my way out of it?

Comment: Well, usually an idiom is a phrase, a set of words. But if OP is ok and if you think that such word can be used in this context, I got no problem.

Comment: Idiom has more than one meaning. Another meaning is: the syntactical, grammatical, or structural form peculiar to a language.          Now, could you please tell me, hiw would you translate the word apalabrar into english and express it with one word?

Comment: I don't know that word. You can post a question. :-) I was just expressing my opinion. Your explanations didn't convince me. But it's ok.

Comment: “Oh, I don’t know, but I am not convinced…”.        My friend, i showed you with an example of usage that corresponds to the meaning. You were not aware of the other meanings of the word “idiom”. And you could not translate the word “apalabrar” into english without using an idiom.                                                 But in your opinion, i am wrong. Its all good. Opinions are like, what’s that idiom again? I am not convinced by your smiley face either. Have a great day!

Comment: En la versión del OP no entra el significado de sobornar, propinar o amenazar con "plata o plomo". En el propio texto puedes encontrar "persuade" / persuadir. Una sola palabra que no lleva a ninguna confusión. Gracias por tus lecciones :-)